# php parameters transfer

Tags: php, post, sdk

I try to send some text from my app to php, but somehow I never receive text. What 's wrong here?

```
NSString *name = [[NSString alloc]initWithString: @"Hello World"];
NSString *email = [[NSString alloc]initWithString: @"Ohai2u"];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myhosturlxyz.com/tracktxt.php?name=%@ email=%@",
                       [name stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                       [email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];

NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSData *urlData;
NSURLResponse *response;
urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil];
[url release];
```

The php I made is

```
<?php
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $myFile = "tracktxtf.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, "my posted var is " .$name $email "\n");
    fclose($fh);   
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a wild guess, but might you need `&` between `name=%@` and `email=%a`, making it `name=%@&email=%@`?

Or, can you try using `$_GET['name']` and `$_GET['email']` instead of REQUEST? Perhaps try writing `print_r($_REQUEST, true); print_r($_GET, true);` to your debug file and see what it contains.

Comment: I added the "&" , changed POST/REQUEST same result.

Comment: What is contained in the $_REQUEST and $_GET variables? It shouldn't be a POST, but a GET.

Comment: odd when I look in  logs I see ....tracktxt.php name=.......  It is just like the "?" is not in the string. The content of the name and email variables is send through ok, but the connection between php and the variable is not made....hence the variables are never processed further in the php script.